# 419 auth error trying to set up an Event with Laravel Echo, Vue, and Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-echo

I am currently learning how to properly use Laravel echo an pusher, but the past days I have hit a wall, and I cannot advance nor resolve this problem.

I keep getting the 419 error

```
/broadcasting/auth 419 (proxy reauthentication required)
```

But I don't see where is the problem

I have a method in a controller that fires up the event after a message is inserted

```
/** The headers of the controller class **/

use App\Message;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use App\Events\MessagePosted;


/*The event that is fired*/

event ( new MessagePosted($msg, Auth::user()) );
```

Where $msg is a Message instance.

This is the event class Message Posted.

```
class MessagePosted implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Message
     *
     * @var Message
     */
     public $message;

    /**
     * User
     *
     * @var User
     */
     public $user;

    public function __construct(Message $message, User $user)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('chatroom.'.$this->message);
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('chatroom.{$message}', function ($user, $message){
    return $user->id == $message->id_sender || $user->id == $message->id_receiver;
});
```

Other than that I don't know what could be causing the error, i got everything I read on the laravel documentation and on some SO questions

On broadcasting.php I got:

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],
...
];
```

On bootstrap.js I uncommented the lines the documentation said:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key : "I PLACED MY APP KEY DIRECTY HERE"
    cluster : "us2"
});
```

On my broadcast service provider

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes();

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```